# Retrieve article URL from phpMyAdmin

Tags: joomla-3.x, mysql, sql

I am migrating a site from Joomla to WordPress. The migration tool didn't setup redirects for the old urls so I'm planning to write something to do them for me. I need a way to output all the current urls from Joomla in mysql. Anyone know how I would do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jroute and contenthelperroute to get the sef urls.

```
JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getArticleRoute($id, $catid, $language));
```

If you only have the article ID's you can try this without $catid and $language. They are optional.